# en mi index de logeo me aparece este error Notice: Undefined index: er in C:\xampp\htdocs\consultorio\index.php on line 27

Tags: php

este es mi codigo

```
<body>

    <div class="login-card">
    <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
    <div id="divImg"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"  alt=""></div>
  <form action="src/procLogin.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user" pattern="[a-zA-z1-90nÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ. ]+" placeholder="Usuario">
    <input type="password" name="password" pattern="[a-zA-Z1-90.-]+" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="Entrar">
    <p><a href="web/calendar.php">Agendar cita sin usuario</a></p>
    <?php 
        if ($_GET["er"] == "cch") { ?>
            <div class="login-help">

                <p>Usuario o Contraseña Incorrecta</p>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este error?
Busco a alguien que me ayuda a actualizar este pequeño proyecto es php y css

Comment: Esto `$_GET["er"]` de donde llega?

Comment: Debes poner el archivo completo y indicar en que linea del código te da el error, pues según dice linea 27 pero en la publicación no se puede percibir  la numeración

Comment: De igual manera, además de lo que dice @Santiago no nos muestras como estás enviándole a ese archivo la variable `$_GET["er"]`

Comment: como puedo mostrarles el codigo completo, soy nuevo y no he podido resolver el problema la linea 27 es if ($_GET["er"] == "cch")

Answer (score 0):

Estás validando que el índice *er* enviado a través de GET sea igual que el valor *cch*, pero también tienes que tener en cuenta si dicho índice existe para que no muestre el error, ya que es posible que no estés enviándolo.

Así pues, el código debería ser algo así:

```
<body>

    <div class="login-card">
    <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
    <div id="divImg"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"  alt=""></div>
  <form action="src/procLogin.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user" pattern="[a-zA-z1-90nÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ. ]+" placeholder="Usuario">
    <input type="password" name="password" pattern="[a-zA-Z1-90.-]+" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="Entrar">
    <p><a href="web/calendar.php">Agendar cita sin usuario</a></p>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_GET["er"]) && $_GET["er"] == "cch") { ?>
            <div class="login-help">

                <p>Usuario o Contraseña Incorrecta</p>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

El único cambio pasaría por validar si existe el índice *er* en GET utilizando [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php). Esto debería solucionarlo.

Cada vez que envíes un valor a través de GET, POST, etc. deberías validar que el índice existe, así evitarás errores como este.

Comment: Hola realice el cambio como lo sugeriste pero sigue el mismo error, mira este es el código completo, como podría mostrarte el codigo completo de esta parte?

Comment: la variable tecnicamente  se deberia  de poner sola en la url/directorio/archivo.php?variable= pero lo dejo de hacer

Comment: Acabo de probar el código que publicaste en tu pregunta y, efectivamente, el error aparece. Cuando aplico el cambio que te sugerí el error deja de salir, ¿estás seguro de que has incluido bien el cambio? ¿hay alguna otra parte del código del fichero que te está fallanado en el que llames a $_GET["er"]?