# Notice: Undefined index: op in C:\xampp\htdocs\consultorio\web\pacientes.php on line 6

Tags: php

¿Alguien que pudiese ayudarme?

¿Que este interesado en apoyarme a trabajar en este proyecto?

Tengo este error Notice:

> Undefined index: op in C:\xampp\htdocs\consultorio\web\pacientes.php on line 6

El código es:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!($_SESSION['id_paciente'])){
    header("location: ../index.php?holo");
}
/*linea 6*/ switch ($_GET["op"]) {
    case 'pacienteVerInter':
        $contenido = "pacienteLog.php";
        break;
    case 'descargarArchivo':
        $contenido = "descargarArchivoLog.php";
        break;
    default:
        $contenido = "v.php";
        break;
}
```

Comment: ¿De dónde llega este valor `$_GET["op"]`?

Comment: Es el mismo caso que otra pregunta que has formulado previamente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/295739/en-mi-index-de-logeo-me-aparece-este-error-notice-undefined-index-er-in-c-xam/295793?noredirect=1#comment542687_295793

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente te dice que la variable **op** no está en el arreglo de `$_GET`. Necesitas confirmar que **op** venga en tu `URL`, por ejemplo: `misitio.com?op=34`.

Ahora, si estás usando `MOD_REWRITE` en tu `htaccess`, hay que revisar bien la expresión regular que generas.